# Printing coordinates in a certain range

Tags: python, split, range, coordinates

I am currently running a code that prints coordinates if the conditions are met, it looks like this and runs completely fine.

```
y=[]
with open('insert my top secret super file here') as protein:
      for i in protein:
          i=i.split()
          coords=[]
          if i[0]=="ATOM" and i[2]=="CA" and i[4]=="A":
              coords.append(float(i[6]))
              coords.append(float(i[7]))
              coords.append(float(i[8]))
              y.append(coords)
 print (y)
```

I now want to print the coordinates if `i[5]` is in range 1–288, but when I add it to the line like this:

```
if i[0]=="ATOM" and i[2]=="CA" and i[4]=="A" and i[5] is in range(1,288):
```

The only thing that prints out is:

```
[]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Here, some sample data so we can try your code and provide a working solution.

Comment: would `i[5]` be an integer between 1 and 288? you might need to try `int(i[5])` as i believe it would be a string

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some sample data that gives you the empty `[]` results.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `is`.

The syntax is:

```
if i[0]=="ATOM" and i[2]=="CA" and i[4]=="A" and i[5] in range(1,289):
```

And @Pwuurple's comment is spot on, you probably have to use `int(i[5])` as well.

note: I tested this on python3.

Comment: To check for value in the range of 1–288 inclusive would require a `… in range(1, 289)`.

Comment: Indeed, corrected, thanks!

Comment: Thank you both so much for answering, but with this it is still only printing "[]".

Comment: Without sample data file, I can't test completely.  I just know `is in` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a lower and upper bound with a chained comparison.

```
if i[0]=="ATOM" and i[2]=="CA" and i[4]=="A" and (1 <= i[5] < 288):
```

---

[6.10. Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)